# Get list of user's friends using my app and offline publishing to user's stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0

I need to perform a couple of actions when the user is logged off Facebook.

First i need to get a list of a given user friends using my application.
Second i need to be able to post messages to user's feeds offline as well.

What kind of permission do i need for that?

How do i achieve it using the Open Graph and the new oAuth 2.0?

What happens if the user initially grant the required permissions but between that and my 
app doing the offline work the user revoke them?

How can i check for that?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I do not believe you are able to get a list of users that have installed your application. That would be the perfect way to send messages to users, trying to get them to purchase something, which despite the fact I hate Facebook they are not that evil.  Everything else you describe would be based on the permissions given to you by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask for the `offline_access` permission.

It's being deprecated but there's workarounds with the latest information as of yesterday that allows us 60 days of access using a token.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

Comment: What about publish_stream? Will i be able to post while the user is offline?

Comment: yes, per publish_stream's current documentation, you will be able to.